# how to check the defintion of a particular environment?

Tags: texlive, linux

What program can be used to output the definition of some macros or some environments provided by a particular package without having to read all the package file. A program that output only the needed definition.

example:
how to check the definition of the `TheSolution` environment provided by the `exam` class

Comment: You can find it in the `cls` file. For example, here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam you find the class. Of course, if you have it in your machine, you can open it.

Comment: `\show\thesolution` (to the terminal) or `\meaning\thesolution` (to the document) or (better) read the source file for the exam class

Comment: `\meaning` does the job. Thank you all

Comment: You may want to use `\texttt{\meaning<macro name>}` then, because otherwise backslashes won't be typeset correctly (unless you're using `fontenc`).

Comment: @Circumscribe my question is not where but how to find the definition. I am sorry if my question is not very clear. I will update my edit.

Comment: Both `\show` and `\meaning` can actually also be found in the answers to that question, as well as the fabulous `texdef` command line tool (which I highly recommend if you plan to do this often).

Comment: @Circumscribe I was actually looking for texdef but I forget it's name. So thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program you're thinking of is `texdef`, by Martin Sharrer. It can be found [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdef), but should already be included with your TeX distribution.

To find out how a macro is defined, you can type `latexdef <macro>` or `texdef -t latex <macro>` (if the first one doesn't work), where `<macro>` is the name of the command you are interested in (without the initial `\`!).

If you want to know the definition when certain packages or classes are loaded, you can tell latexdef using `-p [<options]<package>` flag and `-c [<options>]<class>` respectively (`article` is used if no class is specified). 
To find out how `TheSolution` is defined if `hyperref` is loaded with the draft option (which actually makes no difference), you would for instance type

```
latexdef -c exam -p [draft]hyperref -E TheSolution
```

I added `-E` because `TheSolution` is an environment, so the definition of `endTheSolution` is also shown. If `TheSolution` had been a (dimension, skip, count, token sequence, …) register I would instead have ve added `-v` to see its value.

To figure out in which file a macro is defined you can `-f`, and you can then find out where this file is located using `kpsewhich <filename>`. If `latexdef` says that a macro is defined by LaTeX then it can probably be found in `latex.ltx`, in `fontmath.ltx`, or in one of the other files in the same directory.

There are many more options, which you can see by running `texdef -h` or by looking at the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/texdef/texdef.pdf).